# Word task pane add-in

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I've followed the instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=visualstudio but when I click the debug button in visual studio 2022 it opens word then I open the task pane and I get the following error " Add-In Error: The add-in could not be started. Please restart all Office applications and try again. "

I have also tried to create a new visual studio word add-in project and run that without using the html / js provided in the tutorial from microsoft above. When I do this I get the same error. Has anyone else run into this before? I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to do since the default project template won't even run.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Is the Protected mode enabled in Internet Properties?